# Spring Batch CommandLineJobRunner Config class ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have Spring Boot application with 2 different Batch configuration classes using `@Configuration` and `@EnableBatchProcessing`. I am trying to generate a jar file so the jobs can be run using CommandLineJobRunner with different config file as follow:

```sh
    java -jar build/libs/spro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.asd.SpringBatchConfig1 job1
    java -jar build/libs/spro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.asd.SpringBatchConfig2 job2
```

I am building my project using maven with this plugin to set main class:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
               <manifest>
                  <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
               </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

If I run the project directly in IDE both jobs run at the same time. but calling  bellow command result on an exception which says can not found the XML file:

```sh
    java -jar build/libs/spro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.asd.SpringBatchConfig1 job1
```

The Result is ignoring config class and looking for xml file with that name!

```java
    java -jar target/XXX_CXXXXXX_20200622.jar com.mbb.bts.epi.config.XXXXBatchConfiguration updateXXXX
    2020-06-22 13:34:48.962 [main] ERROR o.s.b.c.l.s.CommandLineJobRunner - Job Terminated in error: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com.mbb.bts.epi.config.XXXXBatchConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com.mbb.bts.epi.config.XXXXBatchConfiguration] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com.mbb.bts.epi.config.XXXXBatchConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com.mbb.bts.epi.config.XXXXBatchConfiguration] cannot be opened because it does not exist
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:518)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:564)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com.mbb.bts.epi.config.XXXXBatchConfiguration] cannot be opened because it does not exist
            at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
            ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You have a spring boot based batch application which already supports this. Remove the `maven-jar-plugin` and let Spring Boot handle it. Specify `--spring.batch.job.names=job1` and it will launch job1. Also if you really need 2 specific configs and those are tied to the specific job, you might want to consider creating 2 artifacts instead of putting everything in a single jar.

Comment: +1 for what @M.Deinum said. Split your app into two separate modules and your issue should be solved by design.